# Add CSS class to an element while dragging over w/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to add a CSS class to an element while it is being dragged over a particular area and replace the class once the element is dropped?

I am not looking for this feature everywhere, but only over a particular area.

Comment: Add the class when over, remove and add new class when dropped?

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UI library (with draggable/droppable interactions)?

Comment: Yes, I use drag and drop jQuery UI.

Comment: @Ibrahim AshShohail. I don't need any class before I start dragging. It must be only over a particular area, with class="targetArea"

Answer (score 24):

Yep, it's certainly possible. jQuery UI provides some handy options and events to do this.

For starters, the draggable element can always be referred to by the class `.ui-draggable-dragging` while it's being dragged.

The `droppable` method then provides an event called `over` which will execute a function whenever a valid draggable object is hovered over it. So, inside that function we can refer to `.ui-draggable-dragging` and add a class to it.

`Out` and `drop` events are also offered and we can target the draggable element the same way. Here's how it would look:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    // tolerance can be set to 'fit', 'intersect', 'pointer', or 'touch'
    tolerance: 'intersect',
    // Add .hoverClass whenever #draggable is being hovered over #droppable
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('hoverClass');
    },
    // Remove .hoverClass whenever #draggable is no longer hovered over #droppable
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('hoverClass');
    },
    // Add .dropClass whenever #draggable is dropped on #droppable
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('hoverClass').addClass('dropClass');
    }
});
```

The above code adds a class when `#draggable` intersects with `#droppable` and then replaces that class when `#draggable` is dropped on to `#droppable`. Additionally, `.hoverClass` is removed when the two elements no longer intersect. Here is a [working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5gAf/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice answer. mootools/jQuery drag-and-drop beats the everyloving crap out of HTML5 drag-and-drop, to the point that it isn't even worth messing with HTML5's implementation.

Comment: what is the solution without jquery ui?

Answer (score 3):

i found interesting to use the prepared ui object provided by the callback so u dont have to make a dom query again. every little performance gain is good especially when  using drag & drop  ;-)
...

```
 over: function(e, ui) {
    $(ui.helper[0]).addClass("success");
  }
```

...

best.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need  jQuery UI. With jquery / javascript we can add remove classes.

I'll show how we can do it in JS.

Consider below html,

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragenter="dragEnter(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

upon dragstart ,

```
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("id", ev.target.id);
}
```

upon dragenter,

```
  function dragEnter(event) {
        var id= ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add("mycalss");
     }
```

upon drop,

```
function drop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 var id= ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");
 document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("mycalss");
 document.getElementById(id).classList.add("replacedclass");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Haven't tried it, but the first thought I have is to gather the x,y coordinates, height, width of the area you want it to change the class over. Then, assuming you can get the x,y coords of the object being dragged, when the object is within those bounds, add class, when outside remove class.

Comment: Why do all this work when there is a jQuery plugin to do it? OP did mention jQuery...