# Draggable elements: strange behavior when width or height is over 300px

Tags: html, draggable, behavior

Today I was playing with the `HTML5`'s `draggable` feature and I noticed something **strange** happening when the **`width`** or the **`height`** or both, are bigger than `300px` (`301px` for example).

If the `div` has `300px` or lower, when I **drag** I can see the entire element just with it's `opacity` lower than 1 **(which is good)**. But if the `div`'s size (`width` or `height`) is bigger than 300px I can't see the entire element anymore (has some parts **transparent** than others, depending on the **mouse** location on the `div`).

**[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eEPYq/)**

---

### Why is this behavior and how can I prevent it?

Comment: The jsFiddle is not working at all (FF 22.0)

Comment: @Pieter.I'm using Google Chrome.Try it.

Comment: I see, thanks. Strange behaviour, I don't know why.

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712535/html5-drag-and-drop-no-transparency