# How to get mouseup event after native drag event?

Tags: javascript, safari, drag-and-drop

The implementation of the WHATWG [drag and drop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dnd) supports `dragstart`, `drag` and `dragend` events.

The `dragend` event fires when the draggable object returns to the original position, e.g. try dragging the red box as far as you can and release it. The `dragend` (and "END!" `console.log` message) will not fire until the draggable element returns to the original position (this is most visible in the Safari browser).

```js
var handle = document.querySelector('#handle');

handle.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
    console.log('END!');
});
```

```css
#handle {
    background: #f00; width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="handle" draggable="true"></div>
```

How do I capture the `mouseup` or whatever else event that would indicate the release of the drag handle without a delay?

I have tried variations of:

```js
var handle = document.querySelector('#handle');

handle.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
    console.log('END!');
});

handle.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    console.log('Mouseup');
});
```

```css
#handle {
    background: #f00; width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="handle" draggable="true"></div>
```

Though, "mouseup" does not fire after `dragstart`.

The closest I got to finding an event that would fire instantly after the release of the handle is `mousemove`:

```js
var handle = document.querySelector('#handle');

handle.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
    console.log('END!');
});

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
   console.log('I will not fire during the drag event. I will fire after handle has been released and mouse is moved.'); 
});
```

```css
#handle {
    background: #f00; width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="handle" draggable="true"></div>
```

The problem is that this approach requires user to move the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround is to enable drop on the `document.body`:

```
// @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragover
document.body.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
    // Prevent default to allow drop.
    e.preventDefault();
});

document.body.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
    // Prevent open as a link for some elements.
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Making `document.body` to listen for the `drop` event results in `dragend` thinking that you will move the element to the new position upon releasing the handle. Therefore, there is no delay between handle release and `dragend`.