# Conditionally display element with NgIf only during Observable emission

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have an Observable which only emits when the user is dragging the cursor over a DOM element in my template, the inner observable will re-subscribe every time the outer observable emits.

```js
...
this.mousedown$ = fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousedown');
this.mouseup$ = fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mouseup');
this.mousemove$ = fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousemove');

this.mousedrag$ = this.mousedown$.pipe(mergeMap(down => this.mousemove$.pipe(takeUntil(this.mouseup$))));
```

I would like to conditionally display the element in the template below only when the mouse is down and moving, the element is not renderered until the observable emits its first value, but, when the emission stop, the element is still rendered.

```html
<svg:rect *ngIf="(mousedrag$ | async)"
          ...
/>
```

How to render the element only when user is dragging ?

### Edit

Adding `endWith(null)` after `takeUntil(this.mouseup$)` do the job, but I wonder what could be a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/26533486/9369606

Answer (score 0):

Based on you comment I have updated the code. The condition for your rendering will be true when the element is clicked, hold and dragged. If the element is released from click hold, the condition will become false. The code is quite raw and can be further cleaned :

```js
const mousemove$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById("test"), 'mousemove');

const mousedown$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById("test"), 'mousedown');
const mouseup$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById("test"), 'mouseup');

const downSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
const upSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

downSubject.subscribe(
  (res) => console.log('Area was clicked', res)
);
upSubject.subscribe(
  (res) => console.log('Area was released', res)
)

mousedown$.pipe(
  tap(ev => {
    downSubject.next(true);
    upSubject.next(false);
  })
).subscribe();

mouseup$.pipe(
  tap(ev => {
    downSubject.next(false);
    upSubject.next(true);
  })
).subscribe();

const yourFinalCondition = combineLatest(downSubject, upSubject, mousemove$.pipe(map(() => true)))
.pipe(map(([ds, us, mm]) => {
  if (ds && mm && !us) {
    console.warn('Area is on hold and moving - RENDER!');
    return true;
  } if (!ds && us) {
    console.warn('Area is released - STOP RENDER!');
    return false;
  } else {
    console.warn('NYÖH');
    return false;
  }
})).subscribe(
  result => console.error('Should I render', result)
);
```

NB:

1. `document.getElementById("test")` in my code needs to be replaced with `this.elementRef.nativeElement` for your implementation.
2. Remove all `console.log`. I added them for the convenience.
3. My `yourFinalCondition` is your `mousedrag$`. Also, since you use `async` pipe, there is no need to subscribe for `yourFinalCondition / mousedrag$`.
4. If you keep my solution code as it is, remember to unsubscribe from `mousemove$`, `mousedown$` and `mouseup$` when `OnDestroy` is triggered. Again, no need to unsubscribe from `yourFinalCondition / mousedrag$`, since you use `async` pipe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is precisely the problem that I have, I probably should reformulate the question this way : "How to render the element only when user is dragging ?" The current code, without the ado in the "edit" part of the question, renders the element when user start dragging but it stays rendered afterwards.

Comment: @Thomas, I updated my solution based on your comment.