# Can I force uniform transparancy on an element that's being dragged?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, draggable

I don't think it is (easily?) possible to style an element that's being dragged using the HTML5 draggable="true" attribute. I can live with that if I could force the element to be made uniformly transparent and not radial. It seems that Chrome select radial if the element considered "wide".

I have created a Plunker to demonstrate what I mean: 
http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/Vd5DLescUxAKRg61Q9x7/

The first four boxes are uniformly transparent when dragged, but the two last are radial. It is possible to force a uniform transparency on all six boxes?

(Don't know why the Plunker doesn't work in Firefox. If you know why I will gladly fix it.)

Comment: could you set the opacity to 1 in the draggable function?

Comment: actually look at this it can't sadly be done http://stackoverflow.com/q/9712535/1675954

Comment: on a sidenote use http://jsfiddle.net - cross-browser compatible!