# Drag and Drop displaying wrong ghost image when the object is partially hidden by overflow

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm having trouble with HTML5 drag and drop. Here is a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/timbergus/pen/RaGzqp) with a minimum drag example to illustrate the question.

The problem is that if we have a container with `overflow: hidden`, part of the content could appear incomplete, so when we drag it outside the container, the ghost image created by the browser appears incomplete as the content instead of showing the full element.

In the example, there are two grey boxes, one of them hidden by the overflow, so when you drag it, the ghost image generated does not correspond with the full shape of the element. Is there any way to force the element to show a complete ghost image when dragging remaining the dragged object hidden by the overflow of the parent?

Thank you very much

**SOLUTION**

Well finally and thanks to the clues given by [freestock.tk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5875416/freestock-tk) I have found a solution that works for the example. The trick is using the `position: absolute` but in a cloned object attached to the body and hidden from the user. We need to add the following to the drag event:

```
c2.addEventListener('dragstart', event => {

    // Here we clone the element.
    let clonedElement =  c2.cloneNode(true);

    // And we add our class with position absolute to render it
    // hidden from the user.
    clonedElement.classList.add('cloned');

    // Then we attach the element to the body.
    document.body.appendChild(clonedElement);

    // And we pass this element to drag image of the drag event
    // using the position of the click of the mouse to set it.
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(clonedElement, event.offsetX, event.offsetY);

    // And finally we remove the cloned element.
    window.setTimeout(() => clonedElement.parentNode.removeChild(clonedElement), 350);
});
```

The `cloned` class has the following content:

```
.cloned
    position absolute
    width 100px
    left 1000px
```

And here is a CodePen with the [solution](http://codepen.io/timbergus/pen/ZWBKgr) working.

Comment: maybe the ones who did mark this as off-topic didnt notice the [**pen**](http://codepen.io/timbergus/pen/RaGzqp); I think even with the complete code on pen/jsfiddle, you still need to let the relevent part of the code on the question;

Comment: I have tried to improve the question. Sorry if it was not enough clear but I have not found another way to express the problem. I don't really know if I'm doing things wrong, the browser is doing things wrong or if it is a better way to do this apart from the native HTML5 way.

Comment: I think it is well explained, the only thing that is missing is a piece of code (external isnt enought);

Comment: But there is no way I can put the code inside the question because it is not really my code and it needs to be tested in the browser. That's why I created the pen in the first place. Well, nevermind. Thank you for your help anyway. At least, you gave me clues to continue searching :)

Answer (score 1):

I did add the position absolute on the drag event aswell:

```
let c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
let c2 = document.getElementById('c2');

c2.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
  event.currentTarget.style.position = 'absolute';
  event.currentTarget.style.margin = "10px";
});

c2.addEventListener('dragstart', event => {
  event.currentTarget.style.position = 'absolute';
  event.currentTarget.style.margin = "10px";
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
});

c2.addEventListener('dragend', event => {
  event.currentTarget.style.position = 'initial';
});
```

link: [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXbjJg?editors=0110)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have implemented your solution [here](http://codepen.io/timbergus/pen/jqVNbb), but instead on `hover`, on `mousedow` because I just need it to happen when the user tries to drag the element. The problem is that the element keeps the `position: absolute` and it displays wrong inside the container. And if I try to set the position again in `dragstart` to its previous value, the ghost image appears incomplete again.

Comment: gotcha. [**heres a pen of it**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWBEzx?editors=1100) anyway;

Comment: **answer updated** re-check please.

Comment: Thanks, I have just seen it. One problem solved. The ghost image is displaying correctly and you can set the position of the ghost image to match the dragged element position on `mousedown`. But still it appears to displays wrong inside the container while dragging because the dragged element appears [over the container](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9c4r91c32r1bq5c/Screenshot%202016-03-14%2021.30.16.png?dl=0) instead inside as defined by the `overflow: hidden` property. Is it possible to have booth behaviours? The element inside the parent hidden by the overflow and a full ghost image?

Comment: I got what you mean but I think that's not possible since the 'start ghost' and the 'moved ghost' are 2 views of the same object;

Comment: So that means that ghost image represents the current state of the dragged object and not just a snapshot of the object when it was dragged? So the object dragged should exist somewhere else, full rendered and be a different one than the one we see inside the parent container if we want a proper ghost image? Wow! This is a really messy implementation of drag and drop. Well. Thank you for your help anyway. I will try to find a workaround for this. It has to work :)

Comment: earlier i was reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712535/html5-drag-and-drop-no-transparency) where the conclusion is: isnt even possible to change the ghost opacity;