# Can't the css of the dragged element be modified in the vanilla javascript drag event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I want the dragged element not to be blurred.

[image]

When dragged as in the photo above, the element is blurred. However, I want to keep the element even when dragged like the picture below.

[image]

How can I implement it using only Vanilla Javascript + css without using JQuery, any other library?

```js
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

containers.forEach((container) => {
  container.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY);
    const draggable = document.querySelector(".dragging");

    if (afterElement == null) {
      container.appendChild(draggable);
    } else {
      container.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement);
    }
  });

  container.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    const box = document.getElementById(id);

    box.classList.add("dragging");
  });

  container.addEventListener("dragend", (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    const box = document.getElementById(id);

    box.classList.remove("dragging");
  });
});

function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
  const draggableElements = [
    ...container.querySelectorAll(".draggable:not(.dragging)"),
  ];

  return draggableElements.reduce(
    (closest, child) => {
      const box = child.getBoundingClientRect();
      const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2;
      // console.log(offset);

      if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
        return {
          offset: offset,
          element: child,
        };
      }
      return closest;
    },
    { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }
  ).element;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="box1" class="draggable" draggable="true">1</p>
    <p id="box2" class="draggable" draggable="true">2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <p id="box3" class="draggable" draggable="true">3</p>
    <p id="box4" class="draggable" draggable="true">4</p>
  </div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.draggable {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: move;
}

.draggable.dragging {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The code above is the code I implemented. Currently this code is being dragged, but the dragged element is blurred.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the CSS as well? It appears to be a specificity issue with CSS classes.

Comment: @KK Thank you for answer. The css code in use is also added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this code:

```
.draggable.dragging {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Or modify it as below:

```
.draggable.dragging {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

It will solve your issue

```js
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

containers.forEach((container) => {
  container.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY);
    const draggable = document.querySelector(".dragging");

    if (afterElement == null) {
      container.appendChild(draggable);
    } else {
      container.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement);
    }
  });

  container.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    const box = document.getElementById(id);

    box.classList.add("dragging");
  });

  container.addEventListener("dragend", (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    const box = document.getElementById(id);

    box.classList.remove("dragging");
  });
});

function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
  const draggableElements = [
    ...container.querySelectorAll(".draggable:not(.dragging)"),
  ];

  return draggableElements.reduce(
    (closest, child) => {
      const box = child.getBoundingClientRect();
      const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2;
      // console.log(offset);

      if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
        return {
          offset: offset,
          element: child,
        };
      }
      return closest;
    }, {
      offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
    }
  ).element;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.draggable {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: move;
}

.draggable.dragging {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="box1" class="draggable" draggable="true">1</p>
  <p id="box2" class="draggable" draggable="true">2</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p id="box3" class="draggable" draggable="true">3</p>
  <p id="box4" class="draggable" draggable="true">4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there seems to be a misunderstanding. I want to get rid of the blur when dragging. In the example above, when the li tag is dragged (red bounding box), it moves in a blurry state. (I revised the photo above.) I want to change this state to be as clear as the photo below.

Comment: It's not possible to change the transparency of the dragging element. It might be 
@Taylous possible in one browser but not in others. There is no solution that works across the browsers. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712535/html5-drag-and-drop-no-transparency

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at your CSS? If the `draggable` class contains any rules that blur the element, you may have found your issue. Try removing any CSS rules that you don't need?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I also attached the css used. But it doesn't seem to be a css problem...

Comment: Does removing the `opacity: 0.5;` property fix the issue?

Comment: I couldn't explain the problem in detail. I want to fix the dragged element being ghosted. To further explain with the photo above, when dragging an element marked "4", the dragged element is blurred. I want to move this without blurring like in the photo below.