Is there is way to change default translucent image by browser when onDragStart event fire
I hope you're all doing well, and I appreciate your attempts to help. What I'm trying to do here is practice and improve my skills, so I decided to create a simple drag-and-drop function for an existing list. I'm using the react-beautiful-dnd library as a reference. However, I'm currently facing an issue with the translucent image that the browser generates by default during the drag event. I can only hide this image, but when looking at the react-beautiful-dnd library, the full element appears without any effects. I still don't know how to display the full element, as they do in the Beautiful Drag & Drop library. Can you help me with this?
I will include two images to illustrate what I mean. In my image, you can see that the transparency of the dragged element changes, unlike what happens in the Beautiful DnD library, as shown in the second image.
image 1 from my code

image 2 from react-beautiful-dnd


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712535/html5-drag-and-drop-no-transparency

@CBroe so how react-beautiful-dnd did it ? , am thinking of creating a clone of draggable element and make it's position equal to mouse position to give the illusion of being dragged , am only worrying about performance , any suggestions ?

Anyway, I decided to go with the solution of creating a copy of the element and making it follow the mouse movement while hiding the original element to create the illusion that the element is being dragged. I also improved the animation by using requestAnimationFrame. This is the code I came up with; maybe it will help someone else solve the problem.


export const VideosELEments = () => {
  const [sections, setSections] = useState(DummSections());
  const [draggedSection, setDraggedSection] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const sectionRefs = useRef<(HTMLDivElement | null)[]>([]);
  const clonedElementRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const animationFrameRef = useRef<number | null>(null);
  const offsetXRef = useRef(0);
  const offsetYRef = useRef(0);

  const handleDragStart = (index: number) => (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    setDraggedSection(index);
    if (e.dataTransfer) {
      e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
      e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', index.toString());
      e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0);
    }

    const currentElement = e.currentTarget;
    const cloned = currentElement.cloneNode(true) as HTMLDivElement;
    cloned.style.position = 'fixed';
    cloned.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    cloned.style.opacity = '1';
    cloned.style.zIndex = '1000';
    document.body.appendChild(cloned);
    clonedElementRef.current = cloned;

    const rect = currentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetXRef.current = e.clientX - rect.left;
    offsetYRef.current = e.clientY - rect.top;

    const updateClonedElementPosition = (moveEvent: MouseEvent) => {
      if (clonedElementRef.current) {
        animationFrameRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          if (clonedElementRef.current) {
            clonedElementRef.current.style.left = `${moveEvent.clientX - offsetXRef.current}px`;
            clonedElementRef.current.style.top = `${moveEvent.clientY - offsetYRef.current}px`;
          }
        });
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', updateClonedElementPosition);

    e.currentTarget.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', updateClonedElementPosition);
      if (animationFrameRef.current) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameRef.current);
      }
      if (clonedElementRef.current) {
        document.body.removeChild(clonedElementRef.current);
        clonedElementRef.current = null;
      }
    }, { once: true });
  };

  const handleDragOver = (index: number) => (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (draggedSection === null || draggedSection === index) return;

    const newSections = [...sections];
    const draggedItem = newSections[draggedSection];
    newSections.splice(draggedSection, 1);
    newSections.splice(index, 0, draggedItem);

    setSections(newSections);
    setDraggedSection(index);
  };

  const handleDragEnd = () => {
    setDraggedSection(null);
  };

  const handlMainContainerMove = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (clonedElementRef.current) {
      animationFrameRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        if (clonedElementRef.current) {
          const x = e.clientX - offsetXRef.current;
          const y = e.clientY - offsetYRef.current;
          clonedElementRef.current.style.left = `${x}px`;
          clonedElementRef.current.style.top = `${y}px`;
        }
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    sectionRefs.current.forEach((ref, index) => {
      if (ref) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          ref.classList.add('fade-in-up');
        }, index * 100);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      if (animationFrameRef.current) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameRef.current);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='w-full h-full p-5 relative'>
      <div className='bg-cyan-400 w-fit flex flex-col gap-3 relative p-3 rounded overflow-hidden' onMouseMove={(e) => handlMainContainerMove(e)} onDragOver={(e) => handlMainContainerMove(e)}>
        {sections.map((sec, idx) => (
          <div
            key={sec.id}
            ref={(el) => { (sectionRefs.current[idx] = el) }}
            draggable
            onDragStart={handleDragStart(idx)}
            onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(idx)(e)}
            onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
            className={`
              w-72 opacity-0 hover:cursor-grab bg-slate-50 shadow rounded-md p-2
              transition-all duration-300 ease-out
              ${draggedSection === idx ? 'opacity-0' : 'opacity-100'}
            `}
          >
            <div className='flex flex-wrap flex-col gap-2'>
              <div className='w-5 shadow bg-orange-500 rounded'>
                <p className='text-center text-white'>{idx + 1}</p>
              </div>
              <p className='text-gray-500 font-thin'>الفصل</p>
              <div className='flex justify-between items-center'>
                <p className='font-bold text-xl'>{sec.title}</p>
                <div>
                  <Button variant='bordered' color="primary" onClick={() => { }}>
                    <p> + إضافه فيديو</p>
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



